# Change the color of object at runtime in opengles

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to change the color of my object dynamically in OpenGLES.I put one button on the screen and whenever I click the button, it will show the color picker(Here I am using HUE color picker). And I want to apply that selected color to my object.As I am importing CPP class to colorpickerview class, it will giving the so many errors.Can any one help me out.

Comment: Finally I got the answer.After importing color from color picker, I am reinitialize the whole Opengl part with selected color.